# Have UILabel update when for loop is still going on?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIButton that generates 6 random numbers and shows them on 6 UILabels after the loop is over.

Is there a way to add a delay per label and update them so it looks like the numbers are generated one by one??

Heres the code for my function, I tried using dispatch_async and using usleep in another thread and currently the program works just like how I wanted it to, however I don't know if this is the best way to do it

```
    @IBAction func generateNumber() {
    generateButton.enabled = false
    clearLottoLabels()
    for var i = 1; i<50; ++i{
        lottoNumbers.append(i)
    }


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)){
        for label in self.lottoLabels{

            self.lottoNumbers.shuffle()
            var lotto = String(self.lottoNumbers.removeLast())
            usleep(100000)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                label.text! = lotto
            }
        }
    }

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.6 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        self.generateButton.enabled = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // your UI code here
});
```